# How best to create a warning for the user - when 2 fields from different objects don't match

Tags: fields, warning

First time posting, but a long time lurker.

I have two fields that are basically the same but are on different objects, lets say Serialnumber1 from Account and Serialnumber2 from Lead.

This Serialnumber should match the majority of the time. When these do not match i want to put up and error for the user, just to let them know that these 2 fields do not match..

I was looking at trying a flow to work this out (as i have little to now apex experience).. So i am not sure where to really start with this...
I've had a look at other posts, but only visual force pages seems to show the answer.. so that doesn't help much :(

Many thanks

Comment: Are the 2 objects related in any way? How do you know which Account's serialnumber1 should which Lead's serialnumber2?

Comment: You could have an autolaunched flow component on the Lightning record page that did the query and displayed a result  only if an error

Comment: I was looking into a flow, but couldnt work out how to have it show what i wanted!

Comment: Other than the name of the numbers - they might match and they might not - I don't think there is a real link between the two (as it was "installed" by another company)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the two objects are linked there are a couple of ways of doing this.

1. Formula field: For the scenario that you've listed, you could create a formula field on the Lead if the value of the field within the Lead object does not match the field value on the associated value on the Account object.

Pros:

- Simple configuration
- Ability to add a visual flag
- No processing time required when saving a record as the formula is calculated when the record is viewed

Cons:

- Only works on the object that has the lookup on it (i.e. you'll be able to flag this on the Lead but not the Account)

2. Flow to add flag: You can kick off a record triggered flow when the field is updated on either object. Once you've kicked that off you can retrieve the other object (once again this assumes that they're related in some way). For the Lead, it's a simple retrieval of the Account object and checking if the two values are the same. For the Account, you'll need to retrieve all of the Leads and loop through the records to check each one against the Account and flag both the Account and Lead records that do not match

Pros:

- Can display the flag on either object

Cons:

- More complex build
- Some additional processing time when saving records for which the fields have changed

Comment: Thank you so much for this - Very clear answer and i'll implement one of these today!

Comment: No worries at all. Let me know how if that achieves what you need it to!